# How do you copy file across account with SwiftService

Tags: python, openstack-swift

I look into SwiftClient document on [Cross Account Object Copy](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/middleware.html#cross-account-object-copy)

```
curl -i -X PUT http://<host>:<port>
/v1/AUTH_test1/container/destination_obj
 -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token>'
 -H 'X-Copy-From: /container/source_obj'
 -H 'X-Copy-From-Account: AUTH_test2'
 -H 'Content-Length: 0'
```

and this work fine. But since I have already use SwiftService class from [python-swiftclient library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-swiftclient) but the closest thing I could find is [this commit on cross account upload](https://github.com/openstack/python-swiftclient/commit/1d4d51b218ed14b85d1e46d3e7142fb52ea179d5). Plus it only show how to do it using `Connection` class and not [SwiftService](https://github.com/openstack/python-swiftclient/blob/e1945ea0fac3badd23013b5b559be1f8a79bf114/swiftclient/service.py#L436).

I tried overriding `os_storage_url` when calling [copy method](https://github.com/openstack/python-swiftclient/blob/e1945ea0fac3badd23013b5b559be1f8a79bf114/swiftclient/service.py#L2492) and inside [SwiftCopyObject](https://github.com/openstack/python-swiftclient/blob/e1945ea0fac3badd23013b5b559be1f8a79bf114/swiftclient/service.py#L335) both without success.

Any idea what I have to do here?

---

UPDATED:

I have tried to hack around the library by overriding HTTP headers when `copy` and `upload`.

## Copy

Overriding this method by putting header object into options of `SwiftCopyObject`

```
'header': ['Destination-Account:AUTH_name']
```

This send exactly the same HTTP request to Swift Proxy API as seen in [example 2(The one with COPY method)](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/middleware.html#cross-account-object-copy)

This give me `404` which is the same result of me sending curl to the API manually. Potentially, this could be the correct way if we can get it to work.

## Upload

Following in similar fashion, I added header to `SwiftUploadObject` to specify where to copy from while using Tenant ID of the destination account.

```
SwiftUploadObject(source='/container/source_file.txt', object_name='file.txt', options={
'header': [
  'X-Copy-From:/container/source_file.txt',
  'X-Copy-From-Account:AUTH_source'
]})
```

Doing this get me file not found error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/container/source_file.txt'`. This is probably because it try to look into the destination account instead of the source.

## Success?

I tried changing `source` parameter to `None`. I got `Object upload verification failed: md5 mismatch` error. However, I can see the file is now in the destination container perfectly. The md5 check does not remove the file from destination container when it fail.

While I could use this hack to make this work, I just don't think it is wise to do it on production.